# Efficiently sending protocol buffer messages with http on an android platform

Tags: android, http, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to send messages generated by Google Protocol Buffer code via a simple HTTP scheme to a server. What I have currently have implemented is here (forgive the obvious incompletion...):

```
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
 String url = "http://192.168.1.69:8888/sdroidmarshal";
 HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url);

 String proto = offers.build().toString();
 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sdroidmsg", proto));

 postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

 try {
   ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
   String responseBody = client.execute(postRequest, responseHandler);

 } catch (Throwable t) {

 }
```

I'm not that experienced with communications over the internet and no more so with HTTP - while I do understand the basics... So my question, before I blindly develop the rest of the application around this, is whether or not this is particularly efficient? I ideally would like to keep messages small and I assume toString() adds some unnecessary formatting.

Comment: In fact this was a silly way to do it... aargh... what is a better way?

Comment: I'm assuming it worked then; glad I could help out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Message.toString()` prints out the textual (non-serialized) representation. You probably want to use `ToByteString()` or `ToByteArray()` to get the serialized version, which you can then pass to your URLencoder.
Of course, that will incur some overhead for URL encoding. If you can handle multipart/form-data style POSTs, then you can just attach the bytes directly as a file-part, with `application/octet-stream` MIME-type; that way you'll be sending the smallest possible message, and won't have to worry about URL encoding / decoding on either end.